# How to use @csrf to String in blade.php page from Laravel controller?

Tags: php, laravel, csrf, laravel-blade

[image: @csrf is not hiding in Modal of this page]
After Click on Delete button showing error 419 | PAGE EXPIRED

```
'<form class="delete_form" action="psize/'.$psize->id.'" method="post">
        @csrf
        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE" />
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger mx-2" onclick="return confirm("Are you sure?")">Del</button>
</form>'
```

Comment: `@csrf` is blade syntax, and should not be inside of an echo block.

Comment: Thank you very much your reply leads me to find the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It is solved by replacing @csrf with `<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="'.csrf_token().'" />`

```
'<form class="delete_form" action="psize/'.$psize->id.'" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="'.csrf_token().'" /> 
           <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE" />
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger mx-2" onclick="return confirm("Are you sure?")">Del</button>
    </form>'
```

In Controller Function Destory()

```
function destroy(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $token = $request->session()->token();
        //....
    }
```

Thanks [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/csrf)

Answer (score 0):

You need to concat @csrf

```
   '<form class="delete_form" action="psize/'.$psize->id.'" method="post">
    ' . @csrf . '
           <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE" />
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger mx-2" onclick="return confirm("Are you sure?")">Del</button>
    </form>'
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response but it is not working for me also I am not able to debug with dd() on the bootstrap modal that I am using.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, you are doing @csrf in PHP code which is not parsed by blade. You should instead use function `csrf_token()`

```
'<form class="delete_form" action="psize/'.$psize->id.'" method="post">
        ' . csrf_token() . '
        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE" />
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger mx-2" onclick="return confirm("Are you sure?")">Del</button>
</form>'
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it is generating the token value but displaying it on the Html page.  So there needs a hidden type input tag.

Comment: Sorry, I was too quick to answer. Yes adding `<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="' . csrf_token() . '">` is the correct full solution =).

You are welcome!